# SQL Error on WITH clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to code something like below but getting error:

> If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

I tried to insert `WITH` but it doesn't help.

```
select @flag = 1 from tabC where 1 = (WITH mul AS
(
   SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
   FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
         from   master..spt_values t1)  AS s
)
SELECT *
FROM tabC c
WHERE LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0))
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense, what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can't embed a CTE

Try this

```
DECLARE @flag bit; --semi colon is important

WITH mul AS
(
   SELECT REPLICATE(CHAR(32 + N), 4) AS val
   FROM (select top 95 row_number() over(order by t1.number) as N
         from   master..spt_values t1)  AS s
)
SELECT @flag = 1
FROM tabC c
WHERE val = 1
  AND LEN(CompanyName) > 4
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM mul
              WHERE CHARINDEX(mul.val,c.CompanyName) > 0)
```